# itertools.product slower than nested for loops

Tags: python, performance, python-itertools

I am trying using the `itertools.product` function to make a segment of my code (in an isotopic pattern simulator) easier to read and hopefully faster as well (the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) states that no intermediate results are created) , I have however tested both versions of the code against each other using the `cProfiling` library and noticed that the `itertools.product` was significantly slower than my nested for loops.

Example values used for the testing:

```
carbons = [(0.0, 0.004613223957020534), (1.00335, 0.02494768843632857), (2.0067, 0.0673219412049374), (3.0100499999999997, 0.12087054681917497), (4.0134, 0.16243239687902825), (5.01675, 0.17427700732161705), (6.020099999999999, 0.15550695260604208), (7.0234499999999995, 0.11869556397525197), (8.0268, 0.07911287899598853), (9.030149999999999, 0.04677626606764402)]
hydrogens = [(0.0, 0.9417611429667746), (1.00628, 0.05651245007201512)]
nitrogens = [(0.0, 0.16148864310897554), (0.99703, 0.2949830688288726), (1.99406, 0.26887643366755537), (2.99109, 0.16305943261399866), (3.98812, 0.0740163089529218), (4.98515, 0.026824040474519875), (5.98218, 0.008084687617425748)]
oxygens17 = [(0.0, 0.8269292736927519), (1.00422, 0.15717628899143962), (2.00844, 0.014907548827832968)]
oxygens18 = [(0.0, 0.3584191873916266), (2.00425, 0.36813434247849824), (4.0085, 0.18867830334103902), (6.01275, 0.06433912182670033), (8.017, 0.016421642936302827)]
sulfurs33 = [(0.0, 0.02204843659673093), (0.99939, 0.08442569434459646), (1.99878, 0.16131398792444965), (2.99817, 0.2050722764666321), (3.99756, 0.1951327596407101), (4.99695, 0.14824112268069747), (5.99634, 0.09365899226198841), (6.99573, 0.050618028523695714), (7.99512, 0.023888506307006133), (8.99451, 0.010000884811585533)]
sulfurs34 = [(0.0, 3.0106350597190195e-10), (1.9958, 6.747270089956428e-09), (3.9916, 7.54568412614702e-08), (5.9874, 5.614443102700176e-07), (7.9832, 3.1268212758750728e-06), (9.979, 1.3903197959791067e-05), (11.9748, 5.141248916434075e-05), (13.970600000000001, 0.0001626288218672788), (15.9664, 0.00044921518047309414), (17.9622, 0.0011007203440032396)]
sulfurs36 = [(0.0, 0.904828368500412), (3.99501, 0.0905009370374487)]
```

Snippet demonstrating nested for loops:

```
totals = []
for i in carbons:
    for j in hydrogens:
        for k in nitrogens:
            for l in oxygens17:
                for m in oxygens18:
                    for n in sulfurs33:
                        for o in sulfurs34:
                            for p in sulfurs36:
                                totals.append((i[0]+j[0]+k[0]+l[0]+m[0]+n[0]+o[0]+p[0], i[1]*j[1]*k[1]*l[1]*m[1]*n[1]*o[1]*p[1]))
```

Snippet demonstrating the use of `itertools.product`:

```
totals = []
for i in itertools.product(carbons,hydrogens,nitrogens,oxygens17,oxygens18,sulfurs33,sulfurs34,sulfurs36):
    massDiff = i[0][0]
    chance = i[0][1]
    for j in i[1:]:
        massDiff += j[0]
        chance = chance * j[1]
    totals.append((massDiff,chance))
```

The results from profiling (based on 10 runs per method) was an average of ~0.8 seconds for the nested for loop approach and ~1.3 seconds for the `itertools.product` approach. My question is thus, am I using the `itertools.product` function wrongly or should I just stick to the nested for loops?

**-- UPDATE --**

I have included two of my `cProfile` results:

```
# ITERTOOLS.PRODUCT APPROACH 
420003 function calls in 1.306 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.018    0.018    1.306    1.306 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    1.246    1.246    1.289    1.289 IsotopeBas.py:64(option1)
   420000    0.042    0.000    0.042    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

and:

```
# NESTED FOR LOOP APPROACH
420003 function calls in 0.830 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.019    0.019    0.830    0.830 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.769    0.769    0.811    0.811 IsotopeBas.py:78(option2)
   420000    0.042    0.000    0.042    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

Comment: Can you please give some sample values for `carbons,hydrogens,nitrogens,oxygens17,oxygens18,sulfurs33,sulfurs34,sulfurs36`, so that we can reproduce this and confirm

Comment: That's not how you time code speed in Python. Use https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/timeit.html

Comment: I will retry it with `timeit` and I will add some example lists (apologies for the large size) to the OP.

Comment: you're using append to make chance, and rerunning loop reduce even though you could have multiplied in the for, etc, etc.

Comment: I did indeed. I have adjusted the itertools snippet to correct for what you described, it still remains slower however.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your original itertool code spent a lot extra time in the needless `lambda`, and building lists of intermediate values by hand - a lot of this can be replaced with builtin functionality.

Now, the inner for loop does add quite a lot extra overhead: just try the following and the performance is very much on par with your original code:

```
for a in itertools.product(carbons,hydrogens,nitrogens,oxygens17,
                           oxygens18,sulfurs33,sulfurs34,sulfurs36):
    i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p = a
    totals.append((i[0]+j[0]+k[0]+l[0]+m[0]+n[0]+o[0]+p[0],
                   i[1]*j[1]*k[1]*l[1]*m[1]*n[1]*o[1]*p[1]))
```

---

The following code runs as much as possible in the CPython builtin side, and I tested it to be equivalent to with code. Notably the code uses `zip(*iterable)` to unzip each of the product results; then uses the `reduce` with `operator.mul` for product, and `sum` for summing; 2 generators for going through the lists. The for loop still beats slightly, but being hardcoded it probably is not what you can use in the long run.

```
import itertools
from operator import mul
from functools import partial

prod = partial(reduce, mul)
elems = carbons, hydrogens, nitrogens, oxygens17, oxygens18, sulfurs33, sulfurs34, sulfurs36
p = itertools.product(*elems)

totals = [
    ( sum(massdiffs), prod(chances) )
    for massdiffs, chances in
    ( zip(*i) for i in p )
]
```

Comment: I have removed the lambda chunk (which was a bit silly, I have to agree). Would you say that (in my snippets as they are now) that the remaining difference (of about 0.5 seconds) derives from intermediate values?

Comment: my code gives 0.788 vs 0.562 for the loops, so I guess not much faster

Comment: The difference is already a lot smaller than what I initially observed yet I am still surprised about the noticeable difference in performance with the `itertools.product` function.

Comment: I have to say that I have no further idea in regards to pin pointing what still makes the `itertools` variant slower than the nested for loops since the reduce has been removed from the code and the only difference according to the `cProfiler` comes from the second line in the profiling output (which doesn't tell much).

Comment: I really like how you got rid of extra for loop that I had in there and indeed this implementation makes the performance difference marginal (between both variants), cheers.

Comment: every name lookup in python and python 2 especially is very expensive - if you can get rid of them, you improve the speed a lot.

Answer (score 5):

I timed these two functions, which use the absolute minimum of extra code:

```
def nested_for(first_iter, second_iter):
    for i in first_iter:
        for j in second_iter:
            pass

def using_product(first_iter, second_iter):
    for i in product(first_iter, second_iter):
        pass
```

Their bytecode instructions are similar:

```
dis(nested_for)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              26 (to 28)
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (first_iter)
              4 GET_ITER
        >>    6 FOR_ITER                18 (to 26)
              8 STORE_FAST               2 (i)

  3          10 SETUP_LOOP              12 (to 24)
             12 LOAD_FAST                1 (second_iter)
             14 GET_ITER
        >>   16 FOR_ITER                 4 (to 22)
             18 STORE_FAST               3 (j)

  4          20 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           16
        >>   22 POP_BLOCK
        >>   24 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            6
        >>   26 POP_BLOCK
        >>   28 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             30 RETURN_VALUE

dis(using_product)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              18 (to 20)
              2 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (product)
              4 LOAD_FAST                0 (first_iter)
              6 LOAD_FAST                1 (second_iter)
              8 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             10 GET_ITER
        >>   12 FOR_ITER                 4 (to 18)
             14 STORE_FAST               2 (i)

  3          16 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           12
        >>   18 POP_BLOCK
        >>   20 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             22 RETURN_VALUE
```

And here are the results:

```
>>> timer = partial(timeit, number=1000, globals=globals())
>>> timer("nested_for(range(100), range(100))")
0.1294467518782625
>>> timer("using_product(range(100), range(100))")
0.4335527486212385
```

The results of additional tests performed via `timeit` and manual use of `perf_counter` were consistent with those above. Using `product` is clearly substantially slower than the use of nested `for` loops. However, based on the tests already displayed in previous answers, the discrepancy between the two approaches is inversely proportional to the number of nested loops (and, of course, the size of the tuple containing the Cartesian product).

Answer (score 3):

My strong suspicion is that the slowness comes from the creation of temporary variables/in places adds/creation of a function every time via `lambda` as well as the overhead of the function call. Just to demonstrate why the way you are doing addition is slower in case 2 I did this:

```
import dis
s = '''
    a = (1, 2)
    b = (2, 3)
    c = (3, 4)

    z = (a[0] + b[0] + c[0])

    t = 0
    t += a[0]
    t += b[0]
    t += c[0]
    '''

x = compile(s, '', 'exec')

dis.dis(x)
```

This gives:

```
<snip out variable declaration>
5          18 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
           21 LOAD_CONST               4 (0)
           24 BINARY_SUBSCR
           25 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
           28 LOAD_CONST               4 (0)
           31 BINARY_SUBSCR
           32 BINARY_ADD
           33 LOAD_NAME                2 (c)
           36 LOAD_CONST               4 (0)
           39 BINARY_SUBSCR
           40 BINARY_ADD
           41 STORE_NAME               3 (z)
```

```
7          50 LOAD_NAME                4 (t)
           53 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
           56 LOAD_CONST               4 (0)
           59 BINARY_SUBSCR
           60 INPLACE_ADD
           61 STORE_NAME               4 (t)

8          64 LOAD_NAME                4 (t)
           67 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
           70 LOAD_CONST               4 (0)
           73 BINARY_SUBSCR
           74 INPLACE_ADD
           75 STORE_NAME               4 (t)

9          78 LOAD_NAME                4 (t)
           81 LOAD_NAME                2 (c)
           84 LOAD_CONST               4 (0)
           87 BINARY_SUBSCR
           88 INPLACE_ADD
           89 STORE_NAME               4 (t)
           92 LOAD_CONST               5 (None)
           95 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you can see there is an additional 2 opcode overhead because of the `+=` addition vs the inline addition. This overhead comes from needing to load and store the name. I imagine this is just the beginning and Antti Haapala has code that spends more time in cpython builtins calling c code than running just in python. Function call overhead is expensive in python.