# Return the value of a matching item in a python list

Tags: python, list

I have two lists **myList** and **lookup**.

**myList** contains the item(s) I'm searching for in **lookup**. The match doesn't have to be exact. But once it's found, I would like to return the value '**abc 123**' from **lookup**. Below is my implementation. I'm stuck at the return statement.

```
myList = ['abc'] 
lookup = ['abc 123', 'efg 456', 'ijk 789'] 


def checkIfinLookup(mylist, lookup):
    for x in mylist:
        if any(x in s for s in lookup):
            return ?
```

Comment: return x,  will return 'abc' and not 'abc 123' from the lookup list

Comment: you cannot use `any` then

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you want to return the string that matched the substring, you cannot use `any`, `any` won't keep the value of `s` when `x in s`.

You could use `next` on a search iterator, with `None` as default value if not found. Return from the function if not `None`

```
myList = ['abc']
lookup = ['abc 123', 'efg 456', 'ijk 789']


def checkIfinLookup(mylist, lookup):
    for x in mylist:
        n = next((s for s in lookup if x in s),None)
        if n is not None:
            return n
```

even better, as Stefan hinted, no need to an extra loop & test, just flatten both loops in the comprehension:

```
def checkIfinLookup(mylist, lookup):
    return next((s for x in mylist for s in lookup if x in s),None)
```

Comment: Or `return next(...)` with both loops in the generator.

Comment: @StefanPochmann that's even better. I was trying to set my mind on a one-liner, but didn't think about that! edited. Damn it looks good :) thank you

Comment: @AGNGazer That one is alright, that's nothing like your previous itertools ways :-)

Comment: I figured out that much. Way to go for the attitude!. I'm sure some users downvoted some of my answers & upvoted some. I did the same for some users as well. Some users, well, let's say that I have more issues upvoting them, though :)

Comment: crap, I thought I did well editing your answer. Feel free to rollback. But in that case, `itertools` could be faster than a double loop since it's compiled, so it's not so bad an idea at all (I didn't take the time to bench that, though)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yeah... Probably itertools is better when it is a long nested loop. Then product(*all_lists) saves space. For just two loops your solution is still the shortest and clearest.

Comment: @AGNGazer yeah you're probably right, saves an import and more readable & looks "purer". I found this to confirm what I was suspecting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24555457/itertools-product-slower-than-nested-for-loops. let me edt your post again :) I'm glad I copied your snippet before you delete your comment.

Comment: click on "edited x mins ago" (above my avatar) and choose an earlier revision. Click on "rollback" (I won't remove my upvote whatever happens because I somehow learned a new trick:))

Answer (score 5):

I would just not use `any()` and list comprehension:

```
def checkIfinLookup(mylist, lookup):
    for x in mylist:             
        for s in lookup:                                     
            if x in s:
                return s
```