# How to get rid of multiple nested loops in python

Tags: python

This is my code;

```
instance_count = 10
for imgs in wire_images:
    for counter in range(0, instance_count, 1):
        for oimgs in images_path:
            applyWireAugmentation(oimgs, imgs, wire_dir, odir, 0, dst_dir, counter, "waug")


def applyWireAugmentation(img, wire_img,wdir, odir, theata,dst_path, counter, index):

    src_im = Image.open(wdir+wire_img).convert("LA")
    dst_im = Image.open(odir+img)
    w,h = dst_im.size
    angle = theata
    size = 200, h

    x = random.randint(0,w)
    y = 0
    im = src_im.convert('RGBA')
    rot = im.rotate( angle, expand=1 ).resize(size)
    dst_im.paste( rot, (x, y), rot )
    dst_im.save(dst_path+"/"+img.replace(".png","")+"-"+index+"-"+str(counter)+".png")
```

`wire_images` has all the image files that are in a folder. `images_path` has all the images files in another folder. I need to take one image from `wire_images` apply it on `oimgs` `instance_count` times (10 in this case). Is there any sleek pythonic way to get rid of these loops or to make it faster?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What specific problems are you having or what are you hoping to improve? For speed, have you considered something like [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)? If your code is already working and you can show more of it, you might consider asking at [codereview.se].

Comment: @jtbandes I am thinking of going for multiprocessing but I can't quite wrap my head around it

Comment: `range(0,instance_count,1)` can be simplified to `range(instance_count)`.

Comment: @kaya3 that's cool. I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate all the possible combinations before, but I am not sure if it is better:

```
import itertools
comb = itertools.product(wire_images, images_path, range(0,instance_count,1))

for imgs, oimgs, counter in comb:
    applyWireAugmentation(oimgs, imgs,wire_dir,odir, 0, dst_dir, counter,  "waug")
```

Answer (score 0):

[`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) can be helpful here.

It can transform nested for loops to tuples which you can then use in your final statement.

You code will be like this:

```
from itertools import product   

for imgs, counter, oimgs in product(wire_images, range(0,instance_count,1), images_path):

    applyWireAugmentation(oimgs, imgs, wire_dir, odir, 0, dst_dir, counter, "waug")
```

> Keep in mind that this for loop will not execute if any of the
>   lists(iterators) are empty and it is a bit slower than nested for loop so you have to sacrifice performance a little bit in favor of readability.

Have a look at this Stackoverflow [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24555457/itertools-product-slower-than-nested-for-loops) for more info

Comment: Can you explain it a bit and how its faster?

Comment: @meu it is a bit slower but the OP mentioned that he want to git rid of for loops and this answers addresses that part of question.

Answer (score 0):

As others suggested, one of the best possible way to achieve this is to use a generator which reduces the memory overhead drastically since there is no list to hold in-memory.

```
from itertools import product

wire_images = list1...  # if possible, try to get them in iterator format as well
images_path = list2...   # if possible, try to get them in iterator format as well
instance_count = 10

for imgs, oimgs, counter in product(wire_images, images_path, range(instance_count)):
    applyWireAugmentation(oimgs, imgs, wire_dir, odir, 0, dst_dir, counter, "waug")
```

> The above approach has trade off of time over space and readability.

Comment: This doesn't reduce the memory overhead compared to the original code. The original code also doesn't create any new lists just for the purpose of iterating over the existing lists. Even if you did get rid of the original lists and make them lazily-evaluated generators instead, `itertools.product` would have to create lists out of them in order to iterate over them multiple times anyway.

Comment: You also renamed `counter` to `_` so this will give a NameError inside the loop where `counter` is used as an argument.